# Como ler o conteúdo de um "generator object" do método load_all para arquivo yaml?

Tags: python, python-2.7, load, yaml

Preciso manter uma função que me retorna um generator object de um arquivo yaml. Em outra função eu quero acessar os dados do arquivo yaml.

```
import ruamel.yaml

def load():
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
    with open('davros.yaml', 'r') as stream:
        yaml_config= yaml.load_all(stream)
    return yaml_config

def dictionary(doc):
    dicionario = list(doc)  # ?????? da erro aqui. É esse linha que preciso de ajuda
    print dicionario

doc = load()
dictionary(doc)
```

Então, eu quero manter a função `load` e a partir do retorno dela eu quero criar um dicionário com os dados do arquivo em outra função, nesse caso a `dictionary`.

```
Erro: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jaqueline.prass/Documents/pessoais/teste/arq_ini_yaml/haha.py", line 14, in <module>
    dictionary(doc)
  File "C:/Users/jaqueline.prass/Documents/pessoais/teste/arq_ini_yaml/haha.py", line 10, in dictionary
    dicionario = list(doc)
  File "C:\Users\jaqueline.prass\Documents\pessoais\teste\arq_ini_yaml\venv\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 362, in load_all
    while constructor.check_data():
  File "C:\Users\jaqueline.prass\Documents\pessoais\teste\arq_ini_yaml\venv\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 98, in check_data
    return self.composer.check_node()
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 687, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser.check_node
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 902, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser._parse_next_event
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 911, in _ruamel_yaml.input_handler
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: `yaml.load_all` parece iterar sobre vários arquivos de um diretório; para o seu caso não deveria ser `yaml.load`?

Comment: Pois é, com o load ele já me retorna um dicionário com os dados do arquivo. Mas eu precisava de uma função que me retornasse um objeto, para não quebrar um testes que serão feitos depois. Não sei se isso é possível de ser feito.

Comment: E aí, conseguiu fazer a leitura?

Comment: consigo fazer a leitura dos dados, mas não consegui utilizar a função load. Então estou precisando mudar todo meu arquivo de teste, o que não era o que eu queria, mas enfim, é o que temos

Answer (score 1):

Vamos focar nessa parte do código, que é onde gera o problema que você está enfrentando:

```
with open('davros.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    yaml_config= yaml.load_all(stream)
return yaml_config
```

Quando você usa `with ... as:` para abrir um arquivo, assim que a iteração acaba, o arquivo aberto é fechado e você não consegue acessá-lo mais. Como o `yaml_config` que você retorna é um `generator object` que depende do arquivo aberto, você não vai conseguir mais executá-lo adequadamente.

Então temos que adicionar uma linha no código para executar o `generator object` e armazená-lo em um objeto enquanto ainda estamos com o arquivo aberto, ou seja, ainda dentro do `with ... as:`. Assim:

```
with open('davros.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    yaml_config=yaml.load_all(stream)
    yaml_list=[item for item in yaml_generator] # armazena enquanto está aberto
return yaml_list
```

Dessa forma, teremos todo o arquivo armazenado na lista `yaml_list` e cada posição da lista será um documento do seu arquivo yaml, o qual você vai poder usar para fazer testes. Com isso, você não precisará mais da função `dictionary()`.